# Is every single file in the /dev directory is a device file?

Tags: linux, files, devices

I have read that the `/dev` directory contains device files that points to device drivers.

Now my question is, is every single file in the `/dev` directory is a device file, or does the `/dev` directory contains other types of files?

Comment: Not necessarily. Some of those files are virtual devices. For instance pts, which emulate virtual terminals. ttys are virtual as well, unless it is interface for a serial connection with a development board like arduino

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy Files like `/dev/tty1` and `/dev/pts/0` are device files that points to device drivers, and the device drivers points to **virtual devices** like you said (but the idea is that  `/dev/tty1` and `/dev/pts/0` are still considered to be device files even though they ultimately points to virtual devices).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you may find (b)lock, (c)har, (s)ocket, (l)inks and (d)irectories in `/dev`.  You can see the type with `ls -l`.  However, depending on the OS, you may find other files in there.  eg on NetBSD there is a shell script `/dev/MAKEDEV`, which is meant to help with the creation of these device entries.

As with your other question, it's the *type* of the file (first character of `ls -l` output) that determines if it's a device or not.